# Object library in Xcode 7 not showing all possible objects

Tags: ios, xcode, object, storyboard

I have two different projects in Xcode right now, however they have different object libraries. One is significantly better than the other and has many needed objects that the other doesn't (like a Round Rect Button for example). Is there a reason that one of my object libraries in the storyboard is better than the other? How do I fix this?

Comment: You said you have project A and B, and A is better than B. Then you asked: What is the reason making A better than B? Doesn't sound super logical...

Comment: Make them both iOS projects?

Answer (score 1):

One of them is an iOS project and the other is an OS X project. iOS and OS X use different UI frameworks, hence why they have a different object library. For example, Round Rect Button is an NSButton, which belongs to the Cocoa framework for OS X, and is unavailable on iOS.

Comment: I was watching a video on iTunes U and the guy on there was able to use the Round Rect Button though.